Device is connected (Active) but latest telemetry data not updating
Latest telemetry data not updating....
I am sending data from the esp32 to thingsboard cloud. Device is connected (it shows the active status also). But latest telemetry value is not updating.
Even by using
mosquitto_pub -d -q 1 -h mqtt.thingsboard.cloud -p 1883 -t v1/devices/me/telemetry -u "BmHRkgPVHYBmtDrXJXoi" -m "{temperature:25}"
this command also does not update the latest telemetry value; it only causes the status to become active.
I am trying to send data on the thingsboard cloud. I want to update the telemetry value on the cloud.
